# Binding an event to Spring form select

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, twitter-bootstrap

I want to bind an event on `Spring` form select through `jQuery` and the form is **dynamically generated**( if I understand it right ) because it is inside [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips) modal

here is a sample of my select in the form:

```
<div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="#fileSubjectEL"><strong>Education Level:</strong></label>
    <div class="controls">                  
    <form:select path="fileSubjectEL" id="fileSubjectEL">
          <form:option value="Lower Elementary"/>
          <form:option value="Advance Elementary"/>
          <form:option value="Secondary"/>
    </form:select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to bind a `change` function of `jQuery`:

```
$(function() {
     // EDIT: Added $ missing to ('#fileSubjectEL').attr('class')
     console.log( $('#fileSubjectEL').attr('class') );
     $('document').on('change', '#fileSubjectEL', function() {
          console.log('test');
     });
});
```

But I'm failing. I just want to get the current selected value every time the select is changed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What's not working? Are you seeing console output?

Comment: That looks fine to me (except the 1st console.log, which is missing the `$`).  Get rid of that line to check that it's not just stopping the script running because of a syntax error.

Comment: My friend found the error. I'm assigning the even on the document not on the select it self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$('document').on('change', '#fileSubjectEL', function() {
    console.log('test');
});
```

Should be:

```
$('#fileSubjectEL').on('change', function() {
    console.log('test');
});
```

My friend said that I should bind the event on the `select` instead on the document.